# Trying to make random image blitting at random time in PYGAME

Tags: python, pygame

I have an interesting problem. I need to make such that image must appear every random time in a random place and if it collides with my GAMER it must affect GAMER(some function) with GAMER  for exactly 3 sec and disappear and appear after a random time again.
. I have an idea but it does not work.(note: this is a part of code i already initialized everythiing)

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  
FPS = 30 
playtime = 0
newtime=random.randint(3,10) 
while mainloop:
    milliseconds = clock.tick(FPS) 
    seconds = milliseconds / 1000.0
    playtime += seconds
    if playtime>=newtime:
    image.draw() 
    newtime=random.randint(2,6) #because next appear time must change 
    if collision(GAMER,image):
       GAMER.do_something()  #how to do it exactly for 3 sec?
       image.far_away() #just dissapear for some time
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you talk about an image, then you talk about a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html). A `pygame.Surface` can be `blit()` to the display (respectively the Surface which is associated to the window).  For instance

```py
screen.blit(image, image_rect)
```

You cannot *move* a surface far away. You have to draw the entire scene in every frame and you have to draw (`blit`) the image on the display surface in every frame.
You can change the position of the image. Create a random position when the time span exceeds:

```py
position = random.randint(0, window_height), random.randint(0, window_width)
image_rect = image.get_rect(center = position)
```

When the player collides with the *image*, then set compute the time point 3 seconds in the future. Effect the player as long the 3 seconds are not exceeded:

```py
if image_rect.colliderect(GAMER.rect):
    affecttime = playtime + 3

if playtime < affecttime:
    GAMER.do_something()
```

General process:

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  
FPS = 30 
newtime=random.randint(3,10)
playtime = 0
affecttime = 0

position = random.randint(0, window_height), random.randint(0, window_width)
image_rect = image.get_rect(center = position)

while mainloop:
    milliseconds = clock.tick(FPS)
    seconds = milliseconds / 1000.0
    playtime += seconds

    # handle events (event loop)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            mainloop = False

    if playtime >= newtime:
        newtime = playtime + random.randint(2,6) 
        position = random.randint(0, window_height), random.randint(0, window_width)
        image_rect = image.get_rect(center = position)

    if image_rect.colliderect(GAMER.rect):
        affecttime = playtime + 3
        position = .... # set position far away
        image_rect = image.get_rect(center = position)

    if playtime < affecttime:
        GAMER.do_something()

    # clear dispaly
    scree.fill(0)

    #draw image at the current position
    screen.blit(image, image_rect)

    # update disaply
    pygame.display.update()
```